# How to avoid the #DIV/0! while adding several values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

ok so I've this lil formula in excel

```
 =(J5/(G5*D5))+(J9/(G9*D9))+(J13/(G13*D13))+(J17/(G17*D17))+(J21/(G21*D21))
  +(J25/(G25*D25))+(J29/(G29*D29))+(J33/(G33*D33))+(J37/(G37*D37))
  +(J41/(G41*D41))
```

nothing hard but some of the denominators for the divsions will evalute to 0, for example...

= (9/3) + (5/4) + (2/0) + (0/4) + (2/3) + (5/1)

and I will end up with a #DIV/0! error. Now my question is, how do I have the formula avoid the parts where it divides by 0 and still return the rest of the sum to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `IFERROR` function:

```
=IFERROR((J5/(G5*D5)),0)+...
```

Surround each part by this, if an error comes from it, it results in a `0` instead from the section enclosed within

Answer (score 0):

You could add checks for zero:

```
=(J5/(IF(G5*D5=0,1,G5*D5))+...
```

This will check if `G5*D5` evaluates to `0`. If that's the case, the denominator becomes `1` which is a valid division by one.